# com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ null ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Help guys i want to using firebase to authenticate my apps using custom firebase token, but when the token created and send to my apps firebase cannot authenticate my token and throw

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ null ]

Webservice code

```
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance(instancePatient).createCustomToken(uid2, additionalClaims)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
                            str.setResponse(customToken);
                            System.out.println(customToken);
                        }
                    });
```

My apps code

```
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(userString)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        try{
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        catch (IllegalStateException e){
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        catch(RuntimeExecutionException e){
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        catch(FirebaseNetworkException e ){
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                        catch(FirebaseAuthException e){
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        listener.onSignInWithCustomTokenFailed(task);
                    }
                    else
                    {......
                    }
                }
            }
```

i hope you all understand my english.

Comment: Check did you added `google-services.json` correctly to your project.Go to your firebase condole, than open app settings take google-services.json, And package should match with your application package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out deleteing additionalClaims from createCustomToken resolve the problem. Its because i input a non vaild string to additionalClaims